Using Private Internet Access VPN and attempting to use Split Tunneling
I am using Private Internet Access VPN on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 64gb sd card.  I want to use the split tunneling setting which says that it require kernel process events.
I chatted with their help desk and they said that their Split Tunnel requires the net_cls cgroup in order to work, which is not available on Raspberry Pi OS. If you can get net_cls cgroups working on Raspberry Pi (which you can install yourself) then Split Tunnel should work for you, too.
I used the following procedures and the setting for the feature is still grayed out.
To make net_cls cgroup work on your Raspberry Pi, follow these steps:
#Enable cgroups:
#Edit the /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt file using your favorite text editor with root permissions.
sudo nano /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
#Add the following parameters at the end of the line:
#cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 swapaccount=1
#Save the file and reboot your Raspberry Pi for the changes to take effect.
#Check cgroups:
#After rebooting, verify that cgroups are enabled by checking the /proc/cgroups file:
#cat /proc/cgroups
#You should see the relevant subsystems (such as cpuset and memory) listed.
#Create a new CGroup:
#To use net_cls, create a new CGroup.
sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls
#Mount net_cls:
#Mount the net_cls controller to the newly created CGroup:
sudo mount -t cgroup -o net_cls none /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls
I completed these steps and still am unable to access this setting. I've attached a screenshot.
Thanks for your assistance
